# setting the focus on the nav bar

Tags: html

Does anyone know what css and html code I can use that will set the focus on the nav bar.  In other words I want the page tab such as home page to be highlighted when the user is on the home page. If the user go's to the contact page then the contact page nav bar tab should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in `HTML/CCS` providing your pages have classes or ID's. Using the home example:

HTML

`<body class="home">...`

`<li class="home>...</li><li class="other>...</li>`

CSS

`.home li.home { ... }`

`.other li.other { ... }`

This won't set the `:focus` but it will give you the visual effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of class for your links. An example is to have an `active` class which has some `outline` effect on it or has a different `background-color`. But you cannot achieve that by just using HTML/CSS, you will need some javascript to add and remove this class, based on where you are on your page.

Hope this helps!